# Enterprise Bot Template Exception with Web Chat

Tags: botframework

Created a new project for the Enterprise template, works fine in emulator (development and production), but in Web Chat, after waking it up with "hi", get the welcome card and "What is your name?" then "Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.".  I have found this is due to a MissingMemberException exception at the first line of OnboardingDialog.AskForEmail where it retrieves the state:

```
_state = await _accessor.GetAsync(sc.Context);
```

One odd thing is that the AskForName method is called before this and successfully gets the (empty) state, but then doesn't actually wait for a response.

Any ideas?

Stack trace:

System.MissingMemberException: Property not set and no default provided.
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotState.BotStatePropertyAccessor`1.d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at EnterpriseBot.OnboardingDialog.d__8.MoveNext() in C:\dev\EnterpriseBot\EnterpriseBot\Dialogs\Onboarding\OnboardingDialog.cs:line 62
...

Thanks for any help,

David

Comment: Could you log this as an issue within the [enterprise bot repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/tree/master/templates/Enterprise-Template)?

Comment: Have done [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/issues/228)